# Conditional logistic regression for matched pairs

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to run a conditional logistic regression for data which is similar to the example below:

```
table.10.3 <-  data.frame(pair=rep(1:144,rep(2,144)),
                         MI=rep(c(0,1),144),
                         diabetes=c(rep(c(1,1),9),
                                    rep(c(1,0),16),
                                    rep(c(0,1),37),
                                    rep(c(0,0),82))
                          )
# head(table.10.3)
# pair MI diabetes
#    1  0        1
#    1  1        1
#    2  0        1
#    2  1        1
#    3  0        1
#    3  1        1

library("survival")
fit.CLR <- clogit(MI ~ diabetes + strata(pair), method="exact", data=table.10.3)

summary(fit.CLR)
```

I get the summary. My question is how do I regpresent the result graphically? I need held as I am very new to R plotting. I tried vcd package. I am able to get the mosaic plot for some other dummy data. But I want to plot the results of the clogit model.

Comment: So are you asking how to extract certain sets of results from your `fit.CLR` object, or how to generate a specific type of plot given some input vectors of data?

Comment: He probably just wants a typical S-Curve. I'm not sure how to pull that from a clogit object... typically I would use survfit on a coxph object (clogit seems to inherit coxph) but the results are not what I would expect.

Comment: Carl - Yes. I want to generate a S-curve.  Brandon - I will try the survfit. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get to a survival curve via clogit. Conditional logistic regression doesn't automatically account for survival time; it just deals with membership in strata that contain matched cases and controls the way a Cox model deals with survival times (hence its appearance in the 'survival' package).

If you're interested in estimating the baseline survival and hazard functions, I think you'll need to use a survival model like coxph, or you could just estimate the survival curve directly with survfit.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to plot an S curve the code below will do so.

```
x <- -7:7
y <- 1 / (1 + exp(-x)) #Sigmoid Logistic function
plot(x,y,col="DarkGreen",pch=19,lwd=1)
```

Comment: while this plots a logistic function does most likely not help the TO to understand the model.